# What is the meaning of ${} in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script where function parameters are expressed like this:

```
param(
   ${param1},
   ${param2},
   ${param3}
)
```

What does it mean? I have been unable to find documentation on this.

What's the point of writing parameters that way instead of the more usual

```
param(
    $param1,
    $param2,
    $param3
)
```

?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are both just parameter declarations. The two snippets are equivalent. Either syntax can be used here, however the braced form allows characters that would not otherwise be legal in variable names. From the PowerShell 3.0 language specification:

> There are two ways of writing a variable name: A *braced variable name*, which begins with $, followed by a curly bracket-delimited set of one or more almost-arbitrary characters; and an *ordinary variable name*, which also begins with $, followed by a set of one or more characters from a more restrictive set than a braced variable name allows. Every ordinary variable name can be expressed using a corresponding braced variable name.

From [about_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847734.aspx)

> To create or display a variable name that includes spaces or special characters, enclose the variable name in braces. This directs Windows PowerShell to interpret the characters in the variable name literally.
>
> For example, the following command creates and then displays a variable named "save-items".
>
> ```
> C:\PS> ${save-items} = "a", "b", "c" 
> C:\PS> ${save-items} 
> a 
> b 
> c
> ```

Comment: Additional link: [`Get-Help about_Variables`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847734.aspx). Look for *VARIABLE NAMES THAT INCLUDE SPECIAL CHARACTERS* part.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that even though variable names can include spaces and special characters, but [these are difficult to use and should be avoided](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847734.aspx).

Comment: @vonPryz, the purported problems with these variables aren't well elaborated at MS docs. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 22):

@MikeZ's answer is quite correct in explaining the example in the question, but as far as addressing the question *title*, there is actually more to say! The `${}` notation actually has **two** uses; the second one is a hidden gem of PowerShell:

[image: bracket notation examples]

That is, you can use this bracket notation to do file I/O operations if you provide a *drive-qualified path*, as defined in the MSDN page [Provider Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

*(The above image comes from the [Complete Guide to PowerShell Punctuation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/the-complete-guide-to-powershell-punctuation/), a one-page wallchart freely available for download, attached to my recent article at Simple-Talk.com.)*

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent. It's just an alternative way of declaring a variable.

If you have characters that are illegal in a normal variable, you'd use the braces (think of it as "escaping" the variablename).

Answer (score 3):

There is one additional usage.

One may have variable names like var1, var2, var11, var12, var101, etc.
Regardless if this is desirable variable naming, it just may be.

Using brackets one can precisely determine what is to be used:
assignment of `$var11` may be ambiguous, using `${var1}1` or `${var11}` leaves no room for mistakes.

Comment: To expand on this (since I haven't actually found this officially documented anywhere), the `${}` syntax can be used in the manner described here when retrieving a variable's value to separate a variable name from any arbitrary character(s) immediately following it. For example, if we have a var like `$var = "hello"` and we want to write its value followed by the literal string "there", we can do this like `write-host ${var}there` (to output `hellothere`). This signifies that `${var}` is the variable name. Without the curly braces, PS would think the variable name is `$varthere`.

Comment: Since using non-word chars (alphas/nums + "_") or spaces in a variable name is the exception, this answer elucidates the more prevalent issue of chars actually valid to use in a variable name coming after it. A prime example is the use of underscores ("_") like in a file name/path containing those chars, together in a string using var substitution. Given "$var1" has part of the file path, we'd initially write: "<litPart1>_$var1_<litPart2>.txt". To avoid PS seeing the var as "$var1_<litPart2...>" ("_" + some chars), we'd use the formal var name: "litPart1_${var1}_litPart2.txt"