# What is the purpose of the ${} syntax/operator?

Tags: powershell, operators

Edit: My additional thoughts on the functionality of the operator-

It appears to implement the `IContentCmdletProvider` interface which applies to the `env:`, `function:`, and `drive:` PSDrives. (which is probably how it also interacts with an implicit `variable:` psdrive).  This interface utilizes the `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` cmdlets.

---

I can't find documentation from Microsoft on this feature (it's also really hard to search for symbols in search engines).  I've seen some very weird behaviors that can be accomplished with `${}`.  For example:

```
${C:\Temp\Filename.txt} = 'This writes to the file!'

$ExampleString = ${C:\Temp\Filename.txt} #this gets file content!?
```

In some automatic modules, I also see function parameter variables declared with this syntax `${Message}` and I'm not sure if I should change it to conform with a coding standard or if the syntax actually does something significant (in this example, Jeffrey Snover's MetaProgramming module).  I've used the syntax myself calling variables in string expansion, but that's the only use-case I know of.

So, what gives with `${}`?

Comment: `help about_Variables` - section on "VARIABLE NAMES THAT INCLUDE SPECIAL CHARACTERS"

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That article doesn't explain the weird behavior with `:`

Comment: Yep, It's a reference to a file path. I am trying to remember where I saw that documented.

Comment: So I've tried it on a few more drives and ran across [a reference to the IContentCmdletProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.icontentcmdletprovider?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).  It would appear the functionality is only applied to the `*-Content` cmdlets, but only for the filesystem?  It seems to be a very weird inclusion (or exclusion if you consider the other drives).

Comment: See the answer from Michael Sorens in [What is the meaning of ${} in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647150/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-powershell)

Comment: @vrdse Thanks for that link, didn't see the answer you were referring to at first.  [The link he refers to](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/the-complete-guide-to-powershell-punctuation/) is almost what I'm looking for, but I wish there were some kind of dev-post on why it only exists for one provider.  I'll mark this as a dupe of the other since it tackles most of what I want.

Comment: It also works for env: (e.g. ${env:computername} ) and function: (${function:clear-host})

Comment: @MikeShepard Hm, I suppose those are technically drives as well (although I usually think of `env:` as a scope)

Comment: No, `env:` is actually a PSDrive, not a scope (check the output of `Get-PSDrive`). That's why you can for instance `ls env:` but not `ls global:`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Already aware..

Answer (score 1):

So `${}` has two different purposes. One of them is variable declaration, as it enables you to enclose any special characters in your variable name:

```
${special var with spaces}
```

But also allows you to use it in a larger string like:

```
$Var="middle"
Write-Host "Before${Var}After"
```

Another use cases, as you are suggesting is that it is able to read paths.

```
$Var = ${C:\Temp\Filename.txt}
```

is the same as

```
$Var = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Filename.txt'
```

But also to write to a path:

```
${C:\Temp\Filename.txt} = 'This writes to the file!'
```

is the same as

```
'This writes to the file!' | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Filename.txt'
```